# Python: how to get the first line of several lines that match against a regular expression?

Tags: regex, python-2.7, parsing, line, flat-file

I'm trying to parse an UniProt flat file using regular expressions. Specifically, I want to parse the first line of the series of line containing the features.

Some of the files look like this:

```
ID   FBN1_HUMAN              Reviewed;        2871 AA.SI
[...]
FT   SIGNAL        1     24       {ECO:0000269|PubMed:10636927}.
FT   PROPEP       25     44       {ECO:0000269|PubMed:10636927}.
FT                                /FTId=PRO_0000436881.
FT   CHAIN        45   2731       Fibrillin-1.
FT                                {ECO:0000305|PubMed:10636927,
FT                                ECO:0000305|PubMed:24982166}.
FT                                /FTId=PRO_0000007581.
[...]
```

Some others look like this:

```
ID   SDCB1_HUMAN             Reviewed;         298 AA.
[...]
FT   INIT_MET      1      1       Removed. {ECO:0000244|PubMed:19413330,
FT                                ECO:0000269|Ref.9}.
FT   CHAIN         2    298       Syntenin-1.
FT                                /FTId=PRO_0000184001.
FT   DOMAIN      114    193       PDZ 1. {ECO:0000255|PROSITE-
FT                                ProRule:PRU00143}.
[...]
```

And there are other entries whose first feature line is not followed by "SIGNAL" or "INIT_MET".

I use this regular expression

```
for line in handle :
    ft_regex = re.compile("^FT")
    if sp_regex.search(line) :
         print line
```

And it prints every line starting with "FT". The point is that I just want the first line. I have already tried with

```
for line in handle :
    ft_regex = re.compile("^FT")
    if sp_regex.search(line) :
        print line[1]
```

It prints

```
   T
   T
   T
   [...]
```

Also used the function group() but prints columns, not lines.

I'd be very grateful to get an answer, since I've looking for a long time for a solution but the code I found doesn't seem to work in my case.

Regards,

Bar

Comment: Break down the logic you've implemented and you can see why it's printing every line: for each line, check it against the regex; if it matches, print it. You want to print only one line, you're looping over every line. The solution is to stop looping when you match a line.

Comment: @Welbog thank you very much! I couldn't see the solution despite being so obvious. I really appreciate your help